# Parsing Text file into excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, file, parsing, text

I am new to VBA and I could use a little bit of help for a program which I am struggling with for the past 3 days.
I have lot of data in a text file arranged as 3 columns. This data has to be parsed in an excel
The column 1 corresponds to the time, column 2 the variable and column 3 the value corresponding the variable . 
The excel should parse the data such a way that column 1 has time, and column 2,3,4,5,6,7 the values corresponding to the variables in column 2 of the text file. and the values are in hex datei which has to be converted to decimal. 
here is the code

```
Sub OpenText()
Dim MyFile As Variant
Dim TempWb As Workbook
Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, p As Long, LimitRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastRow2 As Long
p = 2

' Ask the user for the file name to open.
MyFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
' Check for the Cancel button.
If MyFile = False Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set DestSh = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

'Open the Text file with the OpenText method.

  Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=MyFile, Origin:=xlWindows, _
StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
Other:=True, OtherChar _
    :=";", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, _
    1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1)), _
    DecimalSeparator:=".", ThousandsSeparator:=" ", TrailingMinusNumbers:= _
    True
    Set TempWb = ActiveWorkbook
    LimitRow = 1048576 'Version Excel 2010
    LastRow = Range("A" & LimitRow).End(xlUp).Row

         If LastRow > 0 Then

         For i = 1 To LastRow

         If i = 1 Then
            Cells(p, 1).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
        End If

        Test = Cells(i, 2).Value
            If Test = "0x005B" Then Cells(p, 2).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value Else _
            If Test = "0x003E" Then Cells(p, 3).Value = Cells(i, 4).Value Else _
            If Test = "0x0033" Then Cells(p, 4).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value Else _
            If Test = "0x0039" Then Cells(p, 5).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value Else _
            If Test = "0x003B" Then Cells(p, 6).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value Else _
            If Test = "0x003D" Then Cells(p, 7).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value Else _

        Next


  End If
 End Sub
```

The text file looks somewhat like this

```
    2017-03-23_11-48-32.8;0x003E;0x1000
    2017-03-23_11-48-32.8;0x0033;0x01F4
    2017-03-23_11-48-32.8;0x0039;0x6720
    2017-03-23_11-48-32.8;0x003B;0x6720
    2017-03-23_11-48-32.8;0x003D;0x0050
    2017-03-23_11-48-32.8;0x005E;0x1234ABCD
    2017-03-23_11-48-33.1;0x0033;0x01F4
    2017-03-23_11-48-33.1;0x0039;0x6720
    2017-03-23_11-48-33.1;0x003B;0x6720
    2017-03-23_11-48-33.4;0x003E;0x1000
    2017-03-23_11-48-33.4;0x0033;0x01F4
    2017-03-23_11-48-33.4;0x0039;0x6720
    2017-03-23_11-48-33.4;0x003B;0x6720
    2017-03-23_11-48-33.4;0x003D;0x0050
    2017-03-23_11-48-33.4;0x005E;0x1234ABCD
    2017-03-23_11-48-33.7;0x0033;0x01F4
    2017-03-23_11-48-33.7;0x0039;0x6720
    2017-03-23_11-48-34.0;0x003E;0x1000
    2017-03-23_11-48-34.0;0x0033;0x01F4
    2017-03-23_11-48-34.0;0x0039;0x6720
    2017-03-23_11-48-34.0;0x003B;0x6720
    2017-03-23_11-48-34.0;0x003D;0x0050
    2017-03-23_11-48-34.0;0x005E;0x1234ABCD
    2017-03-23_11-48-34.3;0x0033;0x01F4
    2017-03-23_11-48-34.3;0x0039;0x6720
    2017-03-23_11-48-34.3;0x003B;0x6720
    2017-03-23_11-48-34.6;0x003E;0x1000
    2017-03-23_11-48-34.6;0x0033;0x01F4
    2017-03-23_11-48-34.6;0x0039;0x6720
    2017-03-23_11-48-34.6;0x003B;0x6720
    2017-03-23_11-48-34.6;0x003D;0x0050
    2017-03-23_11-48-34.6;0x005E;0x1234ABCD
    2017-03-23_11-48-34.9;0x0033;0x01F4
    2017-03-23_11-48-34.9;0x0039;0x6720
    2017-03-23_11-48-34.9;0x003B;0x6720
    2017-03-23_11-48-35.2;0x003E;0x1000
    2017-03-23_11-48-35.2;0x0033;0x01F4
    2017-03-23_11-48-35.2;0x0039;0x6720
    2017-03-23_11-48-35.2;0x003B;0x6720
    2017-03-23_11-48-35.2;0x003D;0x0050
    2017-03-23_11-48-35.2;0x005E;0x1234ABCD
    2017-03-23_11-48-35.5;0x0033;0x01F4
    2017-03-23_11-48-35.5;0x0039;0x6720
    2017-03-23_11-48-35.5;0x003B;0x6720
```

And also the excel gets created in  a different worksheet instead of the current worksheet.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the problem with your code as written?

Comment: You've got some syntax errors in what you've posted, but the compiler should have flagged them for correction.

Comment: The problem is that the for loop executes only one time and does according to the code, after one loop it arranges itself according to the text file and not according to the code

Comment: Your loop executes for every row `i`.  But you write all the results to the same row `p`.  `p` always = 2.

Comment: I tried by not giving any value to p then I am getting error 1004 and highlights this particular cell on entering debug option Cells(p, 1).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value

Comment: and when giving p a value from 1st to last row also does not give me a concrete solution.. so I am stuck somewhere which i am not able to find

Comment: If you don't give any value to `p`, then getting an error is logical, since your code doesn't know what row to use.  When you step through the code one line at a time, and examine what it is doing on your worksheet, you should be able to figure things out. You will always be writing the contents of whatever is in `Cells(I,3)` or, in the one case `Cells(I,4)` into Row 2 ('p').  If that is not what you want, you have to change `p` each time through to reflect which row you want to write the results.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this resolve ur problem

```
Public Sub Append_text()
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
FLoc = "Y:\Macro\Test" & Format(Now(), "HHMMSS") & ".txt"
Set Stream = fso.OpenTextFile(FLoc, ForAppending, True)
x = 1 'Hoping the start point
Do Until Sheet1.Cells(x, 1) = "" 'U can use the end of file code here for looping till last row
    Stream.Write Sheet1.Cells(x, 1) & ";" & Sheet1.Cells(x, 2) & ";" & Sheet1.Cells(x, 3) & vbNewLine
    x = x + 1
Loop
End Sub

Public Sub Read_text()
Sheet2.Activate
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename
x = 1
y = 1
Set Stream = fso.OpenTextFile(Fname, ForReading, True)
Do While Not Stream.AtEndOfStream
          Str_text = Stream.ReadLine 'Perform your actions
          rdtext = Split(Str_text, ";")
          Sheet2.Cells(x, y) = rdtext(0)
          Sheet2.Cells(x, y + 1) = rdtext(1)
          Sheet2.Cells(x, y + 2) = rdtext(2)
          x = x + 1
          y = 1
Loop
Stream.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not directly on point to the problem but does answer Parsing Text file using VBA.

This is an auto-detect routine.  You can add it to a customized tab by temporarily substituting a Sub line with no parameter and adding that.  Then replace the Sub line with the ***real*** line with the optional parameters.

If you don't specify any of the Optional delimiters, this looks at the first 5 lines of the file and checks for common delimiters. For example, if any of those lines contains more than 8 pipes it assumes pipe is the delimiter.

BEWARE OF THE '**AUTOMATIC COMMA-SPLIT**' ISSUE IN THE COMMENT.  That is an EXCEL quirk, **not** a problem with .TextToColumns.  Excel "remembers" choices **previously** made in the  Data tab when someone used **Get External Data** or **Data Tools > Text to Columns** and might automatically re-perform **that** parsing when the file is opened.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Parse_any_delimited( _
    Optional ByVal dlm_pipe As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal dlm_semi As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal dlm_comma As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal dlm_tab As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal dlm_carat As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal dlm_char As String = "", _
    Optional ByVal no_delim_popup As Boolean = True)


' *** WARNING !!! ***
'
' The FIRST record that EXCEL will see DURING AN IMPORT CANNOT CONTAIN
' COMMAS! IF IT DOES, it interprets those as DELIMITERS and AUTOMATICALLY
' does a field split there BEFORE running any code!  The result is that
' when all text SHOULD wind up in Cell A1, instead it gets parsed into
' cells at each comma.  Then the REAL PARSE routine can only parse what
' IS in the Column A cells.
'
' The "comma parse" UPON LOADING occurs BEFORE any macro runs!

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim check_data As Boolean
        check_data = False

    Dim dlm_other As Boolean
        dlm_other = False
    Dim rcrd As Variant
    Dim leave_for As Boolean
    Dim have_delim As Boolean


'1 ****
    If dlm_pipe Then
        dlm_other = True
        dlm_char = "|"
        have_delim = True

'2 ****
    ElseIf dlm_carat Then
        dlm_other = True
        dlm_char = "^"
        have_delim = True

'3 ****
    ElseIf dlm_tab Or dlm_semi Or dlm_comma Then
         have_delim = True

'4 ****
    Else
        For i = 1 To 5  'Check first 5 records for common delimiters
            leave_for = True
            rcrd = Cells(i, "A").Value

            If Count_Characters(rcrd, "|") > 5 Then
                dlm_other = True
                dlm_char = "|"

            ElseIf Count_Characters(rcrd, ";") > 5 Then
                dlm_semi = True

            ElseIf Count_Characters(rcrd, ",") > 10 Then
                dlm_comma = True

            ElseIf Count_Characters(rcrd, vbTab) > 4 Then
                dlm_tab = True

            ElseIf Count_Characters(rcrd, "^") > 5 Then
                dlm_other = True
                dlm_char = "^"

            Else
                leave_for = False
            End If

      '===============
            If leave_for Then
                have_delim = True
                Exit For
            Else
                have_delim = False
            End If

        Next i

'5 ****
    End If

    If have_delim = False Then
        ' B2 is checked because in certain cases Excel will
        ' AUTOMATICALLY parse data delimited by | or semicolons.
        ' When that happens, THIS sub sees it as "No delimiter Can't Parse"
        ' even though it HAS BEEN parsed.
        If Cells(2, "B").Value = "" And no_delim_popup Then
            MsgBox ("CAN'T PARSE - NO DELIMITER FOUND")
        End If

        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Stops "There's already data here--continue?"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns _
        Destination:=Range("A1"), _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
            Tab:=dlm_tab, _
            Semicolon:=dlm_semi, _
            Comma:=dlm_comma, _
            Space:=False, _
            Other:=dlm_other, _
            OtherChar:=dlm_char

    Cells.Select
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit
    Range("A1").Select

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

' Sub Parse_any_delimited()
End Sub


Function Count_Characters( _
    ByVal str As Variant, _
    ByVal chr As Variant) _
      As Long
    Count_Characters = Len(str) - Len(Replace(str, chr, ""))
End Function
```

Comment: By the way, I created a test tab-delimited text file and opened it in Excel 2016 and Excel automatically opened it with multiple columns.

Comment: I went to use this on a set of rows with only 4 pipes and it gave a "Can't parse, no delimiter found" result (which it should).

I just added 7 pipes at the end of the first line and it parsed.