# How to import txt. file into excel more time effectively?

Tags: excel, vba, time, import, txt

I am trying to import a large txt. file into excel. The whole process works, but is very time consuming (16-17 s). Is there any way to make it more time effective?

My code looks like this:

Sub Dane_wprowadz() ' icon folder

```
Dim Plik As String
Dim Katalog As String
Dim Sciezka As String

CzasStart = Timer

'Screen update hidden
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    

'Gridline hidden
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
    
 'Import of txt file origin
    
    Katalog = InputBox("Proszę podać katalog gdzie znajdują się dane", "Lokalizacja danych", ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\dane") & "\"

'New Sheet
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

'Headers in new sheet

    ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = "Brand"
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1") = "Produkt"
    ActiveSheet.Range("C1") = "Tydzień"
    ActiveSheet.Range("D1") = "Sprzedaż"
    ActiveSheet.Range("E1") = "Województwo"
    ActiveSheet.Range("F1") = "Miasto"
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
  

    'Import txt 1
    Plik = Dir(Katalog)
 
    Do While Plik <> ""
  
  
'Path import
    Sciezka = Katalog & Plik
  
'Data import of the txt file
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=Sciezka, _
        Origin:=1250, StartRow:=2, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
        xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, _
        Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="-", FieldInfo:= _
        Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
   

'Copy imported data to "Dane
    Selection.CurrentRegion.Copy (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dane").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0))
    ActiveWindow.Close False 'close without saving
    
    
    
'Next txt file
    Plik = Dir
    Loop
    
'Start screen upadting
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
'Return to control panel
    Sheets("Panel kontrolny").Select
    
    CzasStop = Timer
    
    MsgBox "Czas prodecury " & CzasStop - CzasStart & "s"

    
End Sub
```

It is probably the txt import that takes up the most time. Is there any way to make it more effective?

Comment: There are many different way to parse a text file. I would probably not use the Data Import function in Excel. So take at look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43344895/4717755) and [this example](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/read-import-text-file/) to get some ideas to try.

Answer (score 0):

Unless VBA is necessary, you can use PowerQuery. I found it to be relatively faster and can do pretty much what you need.

Go Data->GetData->FromFile->FromText/CSV